Container Not found Error while setting up Azure Blob Storage for IOT Edge
I have and IOT Hub and Edge setup in place, for one of the devices I'm trying to create a setup for the Azure Blob Storage module on Azure IOT Edge, I'm following this article.
I have an IOT edge installed on EFLOW-VM and the azureblobstorageoniotedge module is also running. But in troubleshooting logs I'm getting the below error:

[2024-05-15 11:54:05.497] [error   ] [tid 68] [MetaStore.cc:1953] [ListBlobsInOrder] Container not found. Name:iotedgetest
[2024-05-15 11:54:05.497] [error   ] [tid 68] [BlobInterface.cc:1535] [ListBlobsInOrder] ListBlobsInOrder failed. Container:iotedgetest Error:39987

I tried to create the container 'iotedgetest' on the Local Blob Storage using Storage Explorer but I'm getting the below error:
Unable to retrieve child resources
 
ProducerError:{
  "name": "Node Fetch Error",
  "message": "{\"name\":\"Node Fetch Error\",\"cause\":{\"cause\":{\"errno\":-4078,\"code\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"syscall\":\"connect\",\"address\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"port\":11002}},\"code\":\"ECONNREFUSED\",\"errno\":-4078}"
}

The blob storage is connecting in Storage Explorer but creating a container throws this error.
I tried providing access to bind mounts, but that doesn't resolve the error.
EDIT: Adding EFLOW-VM IP's image


Error mentions 127.0.0.1. I don't think it should be trying to connect to 127.0.0.1

Hi Vlad, Thanks for replying. We used ifconfig in our EFLOW-VM and have attached IP's found in the original post. We have tried all of them in the connection string and getting similar error. Please suggest how to proceed.

The error is due to misconfigurations in the module settings. Follow the steps and documents below. The module name is azureblobstorageoniotedge, and the image URI is mcr.microsoft.com/azure-blob-storage:latest.

I used this Azurite emulator for local Azure Storage development:

 "modules": {
          "SampleModule": {
            "version": "1.0",
            "type": "docker",
            "status": "running",
            "restartPolicy": "always",
            "settings": {
              "image": "mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage:latest",
              "createOptions": {
                "Env":[
                   "LOCAL_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME=<local storage account name>",
    "LOCAL_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY=<local storage account key>"
                 ],
                 "HostConfig":{
                   "Binds": ["my-volume:/blobroot"],
                   "PortBindings":{
                     "11002/tcp": [{"HostPort":"11002"}]
                   }
                 }
              }
            }
          },


Replace <mount> according to your container operating system and provide the name of a volume.



API proxy module for nested IoT Edge in a layered network.

Develop and debug Azure IoT Edge blob storage on modules to your device using Docker.

Refer to this SO for connecting an Azure IoT Edge device to an IoT Hub.




For more details, refer to this link for developing IoT Edge modules with Linux containers using IoT Edge for Linux on Windows.
